# Getting lat&lon extent of country by its name using Python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, extents, open-source-gis

Is there any open source GIS function in Python to get lat&long window given only country name? Something like:

```
get_country_window('United states of america')
```

should return:

```
[-135, -50, 22, 50]
```

Comment: Do you mean the center coordinates ?

Comment: @Shady, no I mean the corner extents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function to get bounding box or center coordinate in list given different options for country name:

```
def get_boundingbox_country(country, output_as='boundingbox'):
    """
    get the bounding box of a country in EPSG4326 given a country name

    Parameters
    ----------
    country : str
        name of the country in english and lowercase
    output_as : 'str
        chose from 'boundingbox' or 'center'. 
         - 'boundingbox' for [latmin, latmax, lonmin, lonmax]
         - 'center' for [latcenter, loncenter]

    Returns
    -------
    output : list
        list with coordinates as str
    """
    # create url
    url = '{0}{1}{2}'.format('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=',
                             country,
                             '&format=json&polygon=0')
    response = requests.get(url).json()[0]

    # parse response to list
    if output_as == 'boundingbox':
        lst = response[output_as]
        output = [float(i) for i in lst]
    if output_as == 'center':
        lst = [response.get(key) for key in ['lat','lon']]
        output = [float(i) for i in lst]
    return output
```

Usage:

```
In [42]: get_boundingbox_country(country='netherlands')
Out[42]: [11.777, 53.7253321, -70.2695876, 7.2274985]

In [43]: get_boundingbox_country(country='holland')
Out[43]: [11.777, 53.7253321, -70.2695876, 7.2274985]

In [44]: get_boundingbox_country(country='nl')
Out[44]: [11.777, 53.7253321, -70.2695876, 7.2274985]

In [45]: get_boundingbox_country(country='nl', output_as='center')
Out[45]: [52.5001698, 5.7480821]
```

Answer (score 3):

[Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is a useful geocoding tool. I wrote a simple script a while ago to return lat, long, and name for a given search term - you could amend it to return the bounding box instead.

```
import argparse
import json
import sys
import urllib


def main(args):
    url = u'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?'
    query = []
    if args['street']:
        query.append('street={}'.format(args['street']))
    if args['city']:
        query.append('city={}'.format(args['city']))
    if args['county']:
        query.append('county={}'.format(args['county']))
    if args['country']:
        query.append('country={}'.format(args['country']))
    if args['postcode']:
        query.append('postalcode={}'.format(args['postcode']))
    if args['format']:
        query.append('format={}'.format(args['format']))
    else:
        query.append('format=json')
    if not args['street'] and not args['city'] and not args['county'] \
        and not args['country'] and not args['postcode']:
        query.append('q={}'.format(args['query']))

    url += '&'.join(query)

    results = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    for result in json.loads(results):
        print '{0}, {1}: {2}'.format(
            result['lat'],
            result['lon'],
            result['display_name'].encode('utf-8')
        )


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Geocoding utility')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--street', nargs='+', help='House number and \
                        street name', metavar=('NUMBER', 'NAME'))
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--city', help='City name')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--county', help='County name')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--country', help='Country name')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--postcode', help='Postcode')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--format', default='json', help='Format \
                        [html|xml|json|jsonv2]')
    parser.add_argument('query', help='Query string to search for. Maybe used\
                        instead of street, city, county, country, and \
                        postcode', nargs='?')
    return vars(parser.parse_args())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(parse_args())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download any of the available country border datasets online and use any of the geospatial libraries in Python (fiona, ogr, geopandas, etc.).

For example, download a country border dataset from http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

```
wget http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip
```

After which you can do

```py
import geopandas as gpd

country_df = gpd.read_file("TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp", vfs="zip://TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip/")
def get_country_window(country):
    return country_df[country_df["NAME"].str.lower() == country.lower()].geometry.values[0].bounds

get_country_window('United states')
```

The above returns `(-179.14199799999994, 18.923882000000106, 179.77746600000012, 71.36581400000006)`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @jon_two answer, I will simplify it more. You can make a simple HTTP request as below and get simple Geo data including the Bounding box in the response as JSON  :

**link:**
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=germany&format=json&polygon=0

Comment: fyi - nominatim service includes overseas territories

Answer (score 1):

A solution that also encapsulates the [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/) geocoder.

Using this code:

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

def get_country_window(country_name):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='bbox_by_country_name')
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(country_name, exactly_one=True)
        return location.raw['boundingbox']
    except (AttributeError, KeyError, ValueError):
        return "No bounding box"

print(get_country_window("Ukraine"))
```

will result into `['44.184598', '52.3797464', '22.137059', '40.2275801']`